# Returning value from within $http .then() angular function

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

I have created a service function which returns a location value from an API call to the Facebook graph API

```
    getLocation: function (access_token) {
        return $http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=location&access_token=' + access_token).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data.location.name);
            return response.data.location.name;
        })
    },
```

The console log returns the correct response for what I need to send to the object I am creating in another function

```
    createProfile: function (uid, user, credential) {
        var profile = {
            name: user.displayName,
            email: user.email,
            avatar: user.photoURL,
            location: Auth.getLocation(credential.accessToken)
        };
        console.log(profile);
```

But I am seeing the following in my console. It returns to me a promise object, when I simply want the string being returned inside the .then() response function of the getLocation service.

[Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceN0c.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is: Since $http.get().then() is an asynchronous function so you can not return any value from it. So in this way you will never get the value.
And also you could improved your code as well.

Code is attached below:

### Service Code:

```
getLocation: function (access_token, successHandler) {
            $http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=location&access_token=' + access_token).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data.location.name);
            successHandler(response.data.location.name);
        })
    }
```

### Controller Code

```
createProfile: function (uid, user, credential) {
       var profile;

       function successHandler(response) {
           profile = {
              name: user.displayName,
              email: user.email,
              avatar: user.photoURL,
              location: response
          };
          console.log(profile);
       }
       Auth.getLocation(credential.accessToken, successHandler); 
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just return the promise and execute it in the `createProfile()` function?

Comment: Reason is data manipulation should not be done in controller so suppose we have a situation where we have to parse response before sending it to caller then through this we can always manipulation response before passing it to successHandler. So it is always a best practice to do.